# Shell - check if file contains string with newlines inside

Tags: shell, text

I've declared a string with two newlines inside of string

> somestring=$'\n##### Branch FREEZE enable/disable\nRelease:'

I have a $file with a text inside like this

```
###############################

##### Branch RELEASE enable/disable
Release: disable

##### Branch FREEZE enable/disable
Freeze: disable

##### Mail list #####
```

I am trying to figure out, if there is a string inside with both of the newlines with a command

> if grep -q "$somestring" "$file"; then
>   echo "found the string"

But the result is always positive, when there is a newline inside of string.

How can I make it work correct with newlines inside?

Answer (score 1):

grep patterns are matched against individual lines so there is no way for a pattern to match a newline found in the input.

try pcregrep instead of regular grep:

```
pcregrep -M "pattern1.*\n.*pattern2" filename
```

the -M option allows it to match across multiple lines, so you can search for newlines as \n.